# IE 11 on Windows 8 gets new asp.net session ID after redirect to HTTPS

Tags: internet-explorer, cookies, windows-8, https, session-cookies

I've been notified that a function of one of our web applications that relies on session state is not working. When I tried in both Firefox and IE 11 using the same steps on my own computer, it works for me. So I attached the debugger to the asp.net server process and had the user with the problem try again. I found that the first page adds an object to Session state successfully then redirects to another page. In page_load of the next page, the object is gone and it has a new Session ID. This site is running in SharePoint 2007 and using SQL session. The user only experiences this issue when using IE 11 on his Windows 8 Surface or Desktop. Even then, if he logs in using forms authentication and then repeats the above steps, it succeeds. He also does not experience the problem in Windows 8 using Firefox or Chrome. I tried installing [this hotfix](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2600100) thinking maybe it was the User Agent string not being found but it didn't work. So something about the Windows 8/IE 11 combo seems to be the culprit. Any ideas?

Updates:
I also updated it to use Response.Redirect(page, **false**) to try to make sure the response is not ended without setting the cookie, but it didn't solve it. One evidently important detail I wasn't aware of before is it is also redirecting from http to https. Using Fiddler I've found that on the Windows 8 machine, it does not send the session cookie received from the http response back during the https request so a new one is issued. IE won't share the session cookie between both http and https. This sort of makes sense because your http cookie could already be compromised when SSL is initiated. But *why* is it happening only in IE on Win 8?

According to [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648635.aspx), which granted is old & outdated, session cookies at least used to move freely between http and https:

> If your site has secure areas and public access areas, you must
>   protect the secure authenticated areas with SSL. When a user moves
>   back and forth between secure and public areas, the ASP.NET-generated
>   session cookie (or URL if you have enabled cookie-less session state)
>   moves with them in plaintext...